# Multiplication of list parameter and number parameter

Tags: python, list

I have a function with two parameters, which multiplies to give an output.say for eg:

```
def func(x, y):

    return  x * y
```

This function should be able to multiply if the parameters are numbers as well as if the parameters are an array.
Say, it should work for

```
func(5, 6)
```

and

```
func([4, 5 ,7], [1, 2, 3])
```

And it should return an error if both the parameters are not of the same type(say: x and y should both be a list or x and y should both be integers).. I am new to python and i do not know what I should do

Comment: What should be the result of the list multiplication?

Comment: like [4, 10, 21]. jus the multiplication of elements

Comment: Why do you want the restriction? It would be easy to have `func(10, [4, 5, 7])` result in `[40, 50, 70]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way without using `numpy` , using recursion -

```
def func(x, y):
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) and isinstance(y, (list, tuple)) and len(x) == len(y):
        return list(map(func, x ,y))   #You can simply do `map(..)` for Python 2.x
    elif isinstance(x, (float,int)) and isinstance(y, (float, int)):
        return  x * y
    else:
        raise TypeError("Cannot Multiply")
```

This can handle nested lists as well, throwing error when the lengths are not equal or the nesting of lists are not correct. You can change the conditions as you see fit.

Demo -

```
>>> func(10,20)
200
>>> func([10,11],[20,21])
[200, 231]
>>> func([10,[11,13]],[20,[21, 22]])
[200, [231, 286]]
>>> func([10,11,13],[20,21])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in func
TypeError: Cannot Multiply
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.array` to calculate the multiply :

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, y):
    return  np.array(x) * np.array(y)
```

Demo:

```
>>> func(5,6)
30
>>> func([5,3],[6,7])
array([30, 21])
```

If you don't want to use `np.array` you can use a list comprehension and `zip` function :

```
def func(x, y):

   try:
       return  x * y
   except TypeError:
       return [i*j for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

But note that in this case your arrays should have same length.If they may have variable length you can use `itertools.izip_longest` (in python 3.X `zip_longest`) which accepts a `fillvalue` argument to fill the missed values.

Comment: is there a way without using numpy? and how to check if both the parameters are of the same type?

Answer (score 1):

To check if two objects are of the same type, you can use:

```
def func(x,y):
    if type(x) == type(y):
        #do something
    else:
        return "Error"
```

Answer (score 1):

check type and multible if correct:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, y):
 if type(x) == type(y):
  return  np.array(x) * np.array(y)
 else:
  print "not same type: %s, %s" %(type(x), type(y))
```